# pandas groupby with sum and unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i have the following dataframe

```
amount = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10),name='amount')
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': amount,'price':50})
df['month'] = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','apr','apr','may','may','jun','jun']
df.set_index('month')
```

i would like to groupby 'month', sum the 'amount' columns, and display the price next to each month. we can assume that the price will be uniform within each month, so using a mean() function for example, would work fine.

i am not sure how to combine both the sum() and mean() functions and trying to separate in 2 functions seems to result in loss of info, e.g.:

```
df.groupby('month')[['amount']].sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `agg` function on the `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('month').agg({
    'amount': sum,
    'price': 'mean'
})
```

For mean you you can use the pandas method by putting it in quotes `'mean'` or the numpy means as `np.mean`